# swift クラスでUserを宣言していますが、配列で使ったr、オプショナルとしても使っている意味がよくわかりません。

Tags: swift

Userクラスでプロパティを宣言して初期化の処理もされていますが、
他のクラスで呼び出す時に配列クラスとオプショナルクラスとして２つの方法で呼び出しているのです。
この違いがよくわからず教えて頂きたいです。
初学者です宜しくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: できれば画像ではなくコードを貼ってください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

画像に載ってる範囲だけ見て判断するとselectedUser でしたっけ？がNullならユーザー未選択ユーザークラスが入ってたらユーザー選択済みみたいな使い方をしたいのではないかと思いますが。
Usersには有効なユーザー以外入れたくないのでNullを不可としているのでしょう。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。通常は配列で使っているものがクラス自体を配列にしていることがよく理解できず質問させて頂きました。

Comment: 質問の意図は非オプショナルの配列とオプショナルな非配列の変数の違いではなく配列と変数の違いということですか？であれば単に配列で複数のUserを管理したい。ユーザーは一人しか選択できないのでselectedUserは配列にしていない。ということかと。

Comment: 早々にご回答くださりありがとうございました。［User］（）にする際は配列として使って、User？とする際はselectedUserでアクセスできるようにしているだけなんですね？クラスとクラスが配列になっていたので混同しておりました。スッキリしました。大変ありがとうございました。